# Cómo hacer peticiones sin javascript a servidor?

Tags: mvc, web, aplicación-web, http

Necesito crear una aplicación cuya funcionalidad esencial **no dependa en Javascript** del lado del cliente, solamente de la logica del servidor (cualquier lenguaje de programación [Python, Javascript, Ruby, C#, Go]).

**La logica básica es crear un CRUD (Create, read, update and delete)**. Leer y crear recursos es bastante sencillo pues los navegadores web pueden mandar peticiones GET y POST (a través de formularios) sin ninguna complicación, sin embargo aunque tengo una idea de cómo podría hacer peticiones para actualizar y eliminar recursos, **quisiera saber si como voy a hacerlo** (se los muestro a continuación) **es una buena manera de hacerlo, y sino entonces cómo podría hacerlo.**

**Entonces se me ocurrió lo siguiente:**

- **Para actualizar un recurso:**

En vez de enviar los datos recolectados del formulario a través de AJAX en una petición de tipo PUT o PATCH, podría asignar el método POST al formulario (es bien soportado) y dentro de ese mismo formulario colocar una campo oculto cuyo nombre clave sea "_method" y su valor "PUT", y así poder distinguir en el lago del servidor para hacer las respectivas validaciones y si son correctas entonces comenzar a ejecutar las instrucciones necesarias para actualizar el recurso.

- **Para eliminar un recurso:**

Acá es donde tengo más dudas, porque tengo distintos casos en mente.

Por ejemplo, el más "sencillo" sería eliminar una cuenta de usuario, una vez el usuario esté autenticado su ID se va a guardar dentro de una cookie o sesión para poder identificarlo, por está razón al querer eliminar su cuenta de usuario podría preparar una página con un formulario donde debe ingresar su contraseña y confirmación, esos datos serán enviados no a través de una petición de tipo DELETE porque necesitaria javascript (sé cómo hacerlo) sino a través de una petición de tipo POST (bien soportada en el navegador), si la confirmación de contraseñas es válida comienza la instrucción que se encarga de eliminar el usuario de la base de datos y limpiar las sesiones/cookies, entre otras validaciones.

Ahora, si cambio el planteamiento sobre otro recurso se pone más complicado, no para todos los recursos que se eliminan se necesitaria una confirmación, sino algo mucho más sencillo como dar clic en un botón. Siendo así, lo primero que se me viene a la mente es prepara una ruta `/recurso(s)/:id/delete` pero no es muy difícil ver que esto no es correcto porque se podría comenzar a disfrazar enlaces al estilo `<a href="/recurso(s)/1/delete">Clic para ver</a>` y terminar "engañando a usuarios" a través de la estructura que muestre el documento HTML. Entonces, ¿qué podría hacer en este caso?

**Por último aclaro el que** ya conozco herramientas que utilizan el protocolo HTTP para comunicarse como cURL, HTTPie, y POSTMAN que me ayudarían a hacer tales peticiones sin tener que utilizar javascript, pues se pueden definir el cuerpo de la petición a placer, pero tengo que preparar un documento HTML (vista de la aplicación) que me ayude a consumir la funcionalidad de la aplicación web, y no debe depender de Javascript (como dije al principio).

La aplicación web está basada basada en el modelo MVC.